# Duda con sentencia ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle-12c

Buen día.

Que tal, soy nuevo en Oracle; alguien podría ayudarme a entender esta sentencia.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE WEB2
      LOGGING 
      DATAFILE /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/ dbb.DBF' SIZE 500M
      EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL SEGMENT SPACE 
      MANAGEMENT  AUTO
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sentencia [`create tablespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm) crea un nuevo [*tablespace*](https://selectasterisco.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/conceptos-y-manejo-basico-de-tablespaces-en-oracle/) que, según la definición del artículo enlazado es:

> un almacén lógico de los ficheros de la base de datos. Cada *tablespace* posee uno o varios ficheros (*datafiles*) donde almacena toda la información; estos ficheros deben tener una estructura lógica. Cuando se crea una base de datos, hay que crear al menos un *tablespace*, que por defecto es SYSTEM.

En estos espacios es dónde se almacena la información de los objetos de la base de datos.

Sobre tu sentencia:

- SIPROJWEB2 es el nombre del `tablespace`
- LOGGING indica que el motor de base de datos incluirá en el *log* de la base de datos las modificaciones realizadas en los *data files* del *tablespace*.
- `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/ dbb.DBF` es el nombre del único archivo de datos que va a tener el nuevo *tablespace*.
- El archivo tendrá un tamaño inicial de 500MB.
- `EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL` indica que el *tablespace* se administrará localmente.
- `SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO` indica que el motor auto-gestionará el espacio libre dentro del *tablespace* usando un mapa de bits, y el *tablespace* crecerá de manera automática de ser necesario.

Comment: Gracias jachguate

Answer (score 1):

Por línea:

1) La sentencia `CREATE TABLESPACE` define un nuevo espacio de tablas en la base de datos, en este caso SIPROJWEB2

2) `LOGGING`  determina si se crea registro de la sentencia en los redo log y su correcta restauración desde backup, para no crear registro se usa `nologging`

3) `DATAFILE /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/ dbb.DBF' SIZE 500M` se crea un nuevo datafile de 500 megabytes, un datafile es un fichero físico en los que se almacenan los objetos que forman parte de este tablespace

4)  `EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL SEGMENT SPACE`  en esta linea se define la gestión del espacio, acá se indica gestión de espacio en Segmentos.

5) `MANAGEMENT  AUTO` indicia que la gestión del espacio es automática.